# How to Convert Color-Code Legends from Logarithmic Scale to Actual Values?

Tags: python, plot, colors, plotly, legend

What is the best way to display `actual` vallues in color-code legend when using logarithmic scale color coding in `plotly.figure_factory.create_choropleth`?

Here is the sample code:

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

fips   = df['fips']
values = np.log10(df['values'])
endpts = list(np.linspace(0, 4, len(colorscale) - 1))

fig = ff.create_choropleth(fips=fips, values=values, scope = ['usa'], binning_endpoints = endpts)
```

**Here is what I have currently:**

[image]

**Here is what I wish to have:**

Exactly same as above map except in the legend displaying actual numbers instead of log10(values). For example instead of 0.0-0.5, and 0.5-1.0 (meaning 10^0-to-10^1/2, and 10^1/2-to-10^1) I would like to see: 1-3, 4-10 and so forth.

Comment: can you give an MWE?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Plotly API and since you do not provide a minimal working example, it is hard for me to test, but I am quite confident that you could specify a colormap. If so, then you could just convert the colormap in logarithmic scale while feeding the numbers in liner scale.